# “main cannot be resolved or is not a field”

Tags: android, android-layout, methods

I have two errors in the code below.

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

The error shows that “`main` cannot be resolved or is not a field”.
The suggested solution in Eclipse is to create field `main` in the type `layout`.

```
webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_engine);
```

The error shows that “main cannot be resolved or is not a field”.
The suggested solution in Eclipse is to create `web_engine` in type `id`.

I tried the suggested solutions. In my `R.java`, I added a `main` in the type `layout` and a `web_engine` in the type `id`.
But the problem is not solved. Do you have any idea what can I do?

Here is my full code.

```
package com.sql.greekapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Window;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

import com.sql.greekapp.R;

public class GreekNewsActivity extends Activity {
    WebView webview;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);    
        getWindow().setFeatureInt(  Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS, Window.PROGRESS_VISIBILITY_ON); 

        webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_engine); 
        webview.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
        webview.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);  
        if (Integer.parseInt(Build.VERSION.SDK) >= Build.VERSION_CODES.FROYO)
            webview.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON); 
        webview.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);        
        webview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);         
        webview.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
        webview.loadUrl("http://192.168.10.250/remote"); 



       final Activity MyActivity = this;
       webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
       public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress)   
       {
        MyActivity.setTitle("Φόρτωση...");
        MyActivity.setProgress(progress * 100); //svisimo


           if(progress == 100)
            MyActivity.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
         }
       });

    }

    private class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {          
                return false;            
        }    
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && webview.canGoBack()) {
            webview.goBack();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }    
}
```

Comment: Please translate this question to english, and read the [Stackoverflow policy on languages](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/non-english-question-policy/)

Comment: `R.layout.main` Do you have a "main" in that layout?

Comment: Delete this line and see what happens... `import com.sql.greekapp.R;` - you shouldn't import the `R.java` class.

Comment: Hello, sorry I change the language.

Comment: I delete the import but nothing changed. Do you have any other sugestion? I do not have a main in the layout in the R.java, but I add it later and nothing changed.

Comment: Go to Project -> Clean and than Build your project once.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a common problem. The R.java file is automatically regenerated each time you well let's say make changes. Only problem is changes don't take effect till you save the file and/or clean the project. In the mean time you are using old stuff. Oh and if you have other errors. R.java won't regenerate at all but you still get R.Blah messages. You can delete the R.java file and watch, a few seconds later it 're.generates. So yes just clean and save your project.